# Add link to Kaspersky whitelist in order to unblock it?

Tags: security, firewall, anti-virus, kaspersky

This window appears every 10 seconds saying "Malicious link blocked".

[image]

I believe that the link is secure.

How could I add this link to Kaspersky whitelist in order to unblock it?

Note: I'm using Kaspersky Total Security 2016

The *Details* window doesn't show an option for adding exception. I've checked *Threats and Exclusions --> Configure Exclusions*, it has no option to add *links* but only *files or folders*. I believe this link is not malicious because the website has good reputation.

I've searched the issue and read various articles, manual topics but didn't find something helping me to add a link to exceptions.

Comment: Check the manual?

Comment: i don't use Kaspersky but normally exceptions get added thru the "details" link on a dialog box of that type.  Why do you think it's not malicious?

Comment: The _Details_ window doesn't show an option for adding exception.
I've checked _Threats and Execlusion_--> _Configure Execlusions_, it has it has no option to add _links_ but only _files or folders_.
I believe this link is not malicious because the website has good reputation.